# How to Randomize Text in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking to send three different messages every 10 seconds, currently this is what I have but it is not working. As you can see, every 10 seconds I am getting a random int between 1 and 3 and then using if statements to send the corresponding number. Then from there that should send the text.

```
{
Sleep, 10000 ;
Random, Rand, 1, 3 ;
}

if (Rand == 1)
{
    Send {1}
    Send {Enter} 
}
if (Rand == 2)
{
    Send {2}
    Send {Enter} 
}
if (Rand == 3)
{
    Send {3}
    Send {Enter} 
}

1::

send, test 1

return

2::

send, test 2    
3::

send, test 3

Esc::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

First I don't see that your script is looping, so it runs once and finishes. Then I don't think the bit at the end is needed unless you are specifically wanting to be able to manually press 1, 2 or 3 and have them do something, but that was not mentioned as being your intention.

Try something like this:

```
stopit = 0
While stopit = 0
{
    Loop, 50
    {
        if stopit = 1
        {
            ExitApp
        }
        Random, Rand, 1, 3
        if (Rand == 1)
        {
             Send {1}
             Send {Enter} 
        }
        if (Rand == 2)
        {
             Send {2}
             Send {Enter} 
        }
        if (Rand == 3)
        {
             Send {3}
             Send {Enter} 
        }
        Sleep, 5000
    }
}
return


F10::
    stopit = 1
return

Esc::
    ExitApp
```

Comment: My answer was very basic and works, but I would go with user3419297's answer, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat an action periodically (at a specified time interval) you need a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) or a Loop as in the other answer.

AFAIK SetTimer has higher performance than a Loop and consumes less resources.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook

SetTimer, send_random_text, 10000 ; every 10 seconds
Return 

send_random_text: 
    Random, Rand, 1, 3
    if (Rand == 1)
        GoSub 1 ; jump to this hotkey label (1::)
    if (Rand == 2)
        GoSub 2
    if (Rand == 3)
        GoSub 3
Return

1::send, test 1{Enter} 
2::send, test 2{Enter}    
3::send, test 3{Enter} 

Esc::ExitApp
```